# Why i3 desktop is not scaling to fullscreen in vmware?

Tags: vmware, fullscreen, i3-window-manager

I'm on opensuse 13.2, login manager is lxdm, window manager is i3. When i3 desktop started, the only use the center part of the screen as you see in the below screenshot. If I switch to gnome or lxde desktop, then it will display correctly.

How can make the i3 desktop fullscreen?

[image]

Comment: The screenshot does not look like it shows *i3* but *lxdm*. Anyway, the reason why it works with *lxde* or *gnome* but not with *i3* is probably that *i3* is just a *window manager* and does no automatic screen configuration on its own, whereas *lxde* and *gnome* are *desktop environments* with lots of automatic configurations. You could try running `xrandr --output <YOUR_DISPLAY> --auto` after logging into *i3*.

Comment: one of these options may work for you, but did not work on my setup. https://faq.i3wm.org/question/29/how-do-you-make-i3-pick-up-resizing-the-vmware-window.1.html